# Скрытие дочерних окон средствами WinApi

Tags: winapi, delphi

Здравствуйте! Помогите, если сможете. Нужно написать программу через WinApi: скрыть  все дочерние окна калькулятора и через некоторое время их отобразить. Я написал, но программа работает только с одним окном (если запустить два и более калькуляторов, только один их них будет использован). Подскажите, как можно исправить.

```
program Project3;
uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows;

var
  h: HWnd;
function Callback(h:hWnd; lParam: LPARAM): Bool; stdcall;

begin
  ShowWindow(H, SW_HIDE);
  Result := True;
end;

function Callback1(h:hWnd; lParam: LPARAM): Bool; stdcall;

begin
  ShowWindow(H, SW_SHOW);
  Result := True;
end;

begin
 h :=  FindWindow(nil, 'Калькулятор');
 EnumChildWindows(h,@Callback,0);
 Sleep(1000);
 EnumChildWindows(h,@Callback1,0);
end.
```

Comment: @Владимир1234567, Вы там что-то не то сделали. У меня, при запуске этого кода, сначала закрылись все окна, какие были, а потом открылись все дочерние окна всех программ, скрытые в системе. Нужно делать проверку h<>0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно запустить 2 итерации - одна по окнам калькулятора верхнего уровня, а вторая, которая как раз и будет скрывать дочерние окна - *очевидно, по дочерним окнам каждого из калькуляторов.*

---

*Т.е код должен выглядеть примерно так:*

```
handle := 0
EnumWindows(handle, @TopLevelHideCallback, 0);
```

Далее - `TopLevelHideCallback` имеет примерно следующую логику

```
{ Получение заголовка делается с помощью последовательного
  применения функций GetWindowTextLength и GetWindowText }
if GetWindowCaption(handle, ...) = 'Калькулятор'
    EnumChildWindows(handle, @ChildLevelHideCallback, 0)
```

Аналогично можно поступить и для `ShowCallback` *(когда нужно отобразить окна).*

Answer (score 1):

А теперь читаем внимательно MSDN [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) и [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). И делаем вывод - окна с названием "Калькулятор" у вас нет на момент старта программы, поэтому основной код эквивалентен этому

```
h := null; // FindWindow(nil, 'Калькулятор');
EnumWindows(h,@Callback,0);
Sleep(1000);
EnumWindows(h,@Callback1,0);
```

То есть вы просто пробегаете по всем окнам. Проверка `<>null` нужна всего одна.

```
h := FindWindow(nil, 'Калькулятор');
if (h<>0) then
  begin
  EnumChildWindows(h,@Callback,0);
  Sleep(1000);
  EnumChildWindows(h,@Callback1,0);
  end
else
  writeln('Калькулятор не найден.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, нужно изменить тело программы следующим образом:

```
begin
   h:=FindWindow(nil, 'Калькулятор');
   while h<>0 do
   begin
     //Что-нибудь делаем с окном, например, закрываем
     h:=FindWindow(nil, 'Калькулятор');
   end;
 end.
```

Т.е. ищем окно с заголовком Калькулятор, и пока находим что-то (т.е. указатель не равен нулю) - производим нужную операцию и снова ищем такое окно. Т.о. мы обработаем все окна. Вот только это будет работать, если окно закрывается. Т.к. мы не закрываем окна, то нужно записывать в базу данных (список, например) все указатели, которые уже обработаны. Тогда вместо "h<>0" запишем "(h<>0) and (not уже-есть-в-базе(указатель))", где "уже-есть-в-базе(указатель)" - функция, производящая поиск по всем обработанным указателям.
Но это только один из вариантов.

Comment: Вы пробовали этот код?) Аналог приведу:

    h := 15;
    while h<>0 do
      begin
      {* code code *}
      h := 15;
      end;

И более краткий аналог:

    while 15<>0 do begin {* code code *} end;

Comment: Почему это это не будет работать? Если окно не найдено, то указатель равен нулю. Но я имел в виду, если в конце концов все эти окна будут скрыты.

Comment: Вы после комментария исправили, ага) а если окно найдено, цикл замкнется.

Comment: А разница, открыто оно или скрыто? Окно не будет найдено, если 1) окно закрыли, 2) сменили название. Автор вопроса ни того, ни другого сделать не хочет.