# Как скрыть дочерние окна сторонней программы?

Tags: delphi

К примеру, в калькуляторе и в других программах.

Нашел тут:
[Скрытие дочерних окон средствами WinApi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/43808/delphi-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-winapi)

Вот такой код:

```
h := FindWindow(nil, 'Калькулятор');
if (h<>0) then
begin
EnumChildWindows(h,@Callback,0);
Sleep(1000);
EnumChildWindows(h,@Callback1,0);
end
else
writeln('Калькулятор не найден.');
```

Это весь код программы? Кто-то может объяснить, что именно делается, когда найдется окно Калькулятор? Я в программировании не силен.
Непонятна эта часть кода:

```
EnumChildWindows(h,@Callback,0);
Sleep(1000);
EnumChildWindows(h,@Callback1,0);
```

Что `EnumChildWindows` перечисляет дочерние окна и вызывает какую-то функцию, которая не описана. Мне же нужно скрывать дочерние окна в любой программе, чтобы они вообще не появлялись. Где-то есть полный готовый пример?

Comment: Учитесь разделять задачи на подзадачи. Приведенная функция находит дочерние окна. После того как они найдены, другая функция может с ними работать (например скрывать их).

Answer (score 1):

@Callback - это адрес вашей функции, которая будет вызываться при нахождении очередного дочернего окна. [Полное описание](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) есть на сайте MSDN.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы оно не находилось, а прямо сразу скрывалось при открытии. Типа SW_HIDE.

Comment: Для каждого найденного окна будет вызываться ваш Callback с параметрами. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Один из параметров это хэндл на найденное окно. Чтобы его скрыть вызовите функцию `ShowWindow` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx с параметром `SW_HIDE` из вашего Callback'а.

Answer (score 1):

Внимательно читайте hashcode.ru/questions/43808/

Там всё написано.

```
function Callback(h:hWnd; lParam: LPARAM): Bool; stdcall;
```

Другое дело - работает ли... но - скорее всего.